# subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql problem

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table in MySQL which stores a surname, an amount, a small text, and a date. I want to choose from the entries with the same surname and the same text the entry with the biggest date. So far, I have reached until here:

```
query = """SELECT customer_surname, amount, date_ FROM set_payment7777 WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 GROUP BY type_of_payment) GROUP BY customer_surname)"""

mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
    file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{row[1]}\t")
    file.write("\n")
```

(Notice: `type_of_payment` is the name of the text)

The problem in this code is that this is returning more than 1 row. Any other solutions?

Comment: oh no sorry i am updating it now

Comment: If you are using `GROUP BY` in your subquery, this means it will calculate `MAX(date_)` for each group. In this case, having multiple rows is unavoidable so you have to write 
`WHERE date IN (... subquery here...)`. Or just remove the `GROUP BY` from your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with the operator `IN`:

```
query = """
SELECT customer_surname, amount, date_, type_of_payment 
FROM set_payment7777
WHERE (customer_surname, type_of_payment, date_) IN (
  SELECT customer_surname, type_of_payment, MAX(date_) 
  FROM set_payment7777
  GROUP BY customer_surname, type_of_payment
)
"""
```

Or, if your version of MySql is 8.0+ use window functions:

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT 
       customer_surname, 
       FIRST_VALUE(amount)  OVER (PARTITION BY customer_surname, type_of_payment ORDER BY date_ DESC) amount, 
       MAX(date_) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_surname, type_of_payment) date_,
       type_of_payment
FROM set_payment7777 
"""
```

Comment: I think the `OP` needs only one value the biggest value   based on `I want to choose from the entries with the same surname and the same text the entry with the biggest date.`

Comment: @ErgestBasha this is what both queries do.